# could not broadcast input array from shape (30) into shape (31)

Tags: python, arrays, data-cleaning, shapes, valueerror

I am using this tutorial for cleaning football data. [Tutorial](https://github.com/RudrakshTuwani/Football-Data-Analysis-and-Prediction/blob/master/Prediction/Scraping%20and%20Cleaning.ipynb)

When I try to execute this piece of code for my data:

```
    # Gets the goals scored agg arranged by teams and matchweek
    def get_goals_scored(playing_stat):
    # Create a dictionary with team names as keys
    teams = {}
    for i in playing_stat.groupby('HomeTeam').mean().T.columns:
        teams[i] = []
    
    # the value corresponding to keys is a list containing the match location.
    for i in range(len(playing_stat)):
        HTGS = playing_stat.iloc[i]['FTHG']
        ATGS = playing_stat.iloc[i]['FTAG']
        teams[playing_stat.iloc[i].HomeTeam].append(HTGS)
        teams[playing_stat.iloc[i].AwayTeam].append(ATGS)
    
    # Create a dataframe for goals scored where rows are teams and cols are matchweek.
    GoalsScored = pd.DataFrame(data=teams, index = [i for i in range(1,37)]).T
    GoalsScored[0] = 0
    # Aggregate to get uptil that point
    for i in range(2,37):
        GoalsScored[i] = GoalsScored[i] + GoalsScored[i-1]
    return GoalsScored



# Gets the goals conceded agg arranged by teams and matchweek
def get_goals_conceded(playing_stat):
    # Create a dictionary with team names as keys
    teams = {}
    for i in playing_stat.groupby('HomeTeam').mean().T.columns:
        teams[i] = []
    
    # the value corresponding to keys is a list containing the match location.
    for i in range(len(playing_stat)):
        ATGC = playing_stat.iloc[i]['FTHG']
        HTGC = playing_stat.iloc[i]['FTAG']
        teams[playing_stat.iloc[i].HomeTeam].append(HTGC)
        teams[playing_stat.iloc[i].AwayTeam].append(ATGC)
    
    # Create a dataframe for goals scored where rows are teams and cols are matchweek.
    GoalsConceded = pd.DataFrame(data=teams, index = [i for i in range(1,37)]).T
    GoalsConceded[0] = 0
    # Aggregate to get uptil that point
    for i in range(2,37):
        GoalsConceded[i] = GoalsConceded[i] + GoalsConceded[i-1]
    return GoalsConceded

def get_gss(playing_stat):
    GC = get_goals_conceded(playing_stat)
    GS = get_goals_scored(playing_stat)
   
    j = 0
    HTGS = []
    ATGS = []
    HTGC = []
    ATGC = []

    for i in range(313):
        ht = playing_stat.iloc[i].HomeTeam
        at = playing_stat.iloc[i].AwayTeam
        HTGS.append(GS.loc[ht][j])
        ATGS.append(GS.loc[at][j])
        HTGC.append(GC.loc[ht][j])
        ATGC.append(GC.loc[at][j])
        
        if ((i + 1)% 10) == 0:
            j = j + 1
        
    playing_stat['HTGS'] = HTGS
    playing_stat['ATGS'] = ATGS
    playing_stat['HTGC'] = HTGC
    playing_stat['ATGC'] = ATGC
    
    return playing_stat


# Apply to each dataset
playing_statistics_1 = get_gss(playing_statistics_1)
playing_statistics_2 = get_gss(playing_statistics_2)
playing_statistics_3 = get_gss(playing_statistics_3)
playing_statistics_4 = get_gss(playing_statistics_4)
```

I am recieving this error: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (34) into shape (36)`

My data has 313 records and looks like this:

[Data.head(20)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi8NO.png)

I know it has something to do with the length of the data, but I can't figure out exactly what it is.

Any help is much appreciated, and if any extra information is needed pls tell me!

Comment: The error message usually points to a row that errors. Can you share that please? (Also, I know it's not the point of the question and I'm poking my nose in, but there are some questionable coding practices in that tutorial (lots of repetition) so if you want to learn pandas and not just get the data I suggest looking for other tutorials to supplement)

Answer (score 0):

While there's quite a bit of fixing needed in this tutorial (I'm not going to get into that). I'm not getting that error at all. Is it possible one of the files is corrupt when you downloaded it (I'm getting 380 rows/records, not 318)?? Try changing the first block where you read in the files locally to the code bellow so you read in the file directly from the source. Report back what happens:

```
loc = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RudrakshTuwani/Football-Data-Analysis-and-Prediction/master/Datasets/"

raw_data_1 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2000-01.csv')
raw_data_2 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2001-02.csv')
raw_data_3 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2002-03.csv')
raw_data_4 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2003-04.csv')
raw_data_5 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2004-05.csv')
raw_data_6 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2005-06.csv')
raw_data_7 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2006-07.csv')
raw_data_8 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2007-08.csv')
raw_data_9 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2008-09.csv')
raw_data_10 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2009-10.csv')
raw_data_11 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2010-11.csv')
raw_data_12 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2011-12.csv')
raw_data_13 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2012-13.csv')
raw_data_14 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2013-14.csv')
raw_data_15 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2014-15.csv')
raw_data_16 = pd.read_csv(loc + '2015-16.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The error came from the fact that the different teams in my data did not play the same amount of games so it was missing some from different teams.